# Android: DatePickerDialog cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to implement a date picker into my android application however I cannot seem to find the DatePickerDialog interface.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

}
```

Following the instructions on this page - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

I get the DatePickerDialog underlined in red with an error of `DatePickerDialog cannot be resolved to a type`. Some sort of library or something I need to import? I'm pretty sure I have the support library setup as is.

Comment: Could you show us the import list?

Comment: it's a separate class so the only import in there at the moment is `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that but apparently it's working now >_>... thank you!